# How to write values from the registry to a .txt file?

Tags: c++, windows, registry, msdn

I want to read **REG_SZ** values from the Windows registry and store it in a .txt file.

```
{
      DWORD type = 0;
      DWORD index = 0;
      std::vector<wchar_t> valueName = std::vector<wchar_t>(maxNameLength+ 1);
      //name of value
      std::vector<BYTE> dataBuffer = std::vector<BYTE>(maxValueLength); 
      //Data stored in the value. DataBuffer is LPBYTE value

    for (index = 0; index < valueCount; index++) {
    DWORD charCountValueName = static_cast<DWORD>(valueName.size());
    DWORD charBytesData = static_cast<DWORD>(dataBuffer.size());
    status = RegEnumValueW(hKey, index, valueName.data(),&charCountValueName,  
                NULL, &type, dataBuffer.data(), &charBytesData);

    if (type == REG_SZ) {  //REG_SZ
    const auto reg_string = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(dataBuffer.data()); 
    //Explicit cast of dataBuffer
                printf("\nType: REG_SZ\n");
                printf("\tName: ");
                printf("%ls\n", valueName.data());
                printf("\tData : %ls\n", reg_string); 
              //I want to store this value instead of displaying it
            }


         }
      }
```

I want to check for the presence/ absence of a few words in the data of the value "**Default**" of the registry key and thus want too write the data in a **.txt file** so I can parse it and check for the keywords.

Comment: First of all you need to realize that you're not programming in C, but in C++.

Comment: As for storing null-terminated strings in a file, have you written to files before (using either C++ streams or C `FILE*` and e.g. `fprintf`)? Once you know how to do that then solving your problem should be easy.